# How to transpose a cv::SparseMat in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, sparse-matrix, transpose, mat

I am working in C++ OpenCV and I am trying to solve a traditional normal integration problem; however, to do that, I need to define a matrix with size (2*n_pixels, n_pixels), i.e. (350000, 175000) in my case, each line of which will be filled with only two numbers (a 1 and a -1). I tried to define it as a `cv::Mat`, but the computation becomes terribly slow. Thus, I thought about using a `cv::SparseMat` as an alternative, which works very well, but I need to transpose it and when I try I get the compilation error `error C2039: 't': is not a member of 'cv::SparseMat'`, which I suppose it means that transposition is not defined for `cv::SparseMat`s. How can I solve this?

Comment: I dont have much experience with sparse matrices. Are you able to iterate over all set values and get their element-position? If yes, you could write your own transpose function, iterate manually and set the transposed coordinates in another sparse mat. But probably that's not what you want to do?

Comment: That should be actually right! I will try it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I also had to multiply the matrix by its transposed, and it takes hours to do that if I do it manually...

Comment: probably for multiplying such big (but sparse) matrices you'll have to find some smart optimization that omits most of all elements, but not sure whether this is possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693584/fast-sparse-matrix-multiplication